# Run 'screen -RD' automatically after connecting from PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty, gnu-screen

I would like to have PuTTY automatically run `screen -RD` when I log in, however I would like if possible, for this to be either configured as part of PuTTY, or for the server to identify when a PuTTY user is connected and force `screen -RD`.

I don't wish for this to happen from other boxes, as I don't particularly want this to affect certain automated processes from needing to worry about whether `screen -RD` is already busy and unable to accept commands.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The option is under Connection->SSH in PuTTY's options. Just put `screen -RD` in the remote command field and it'll be executed.

A word of warning: be sure that's really the combination of options you want; as it is that'll close any session you already have open. You may want to use `-Rd` or have some logic based on grepping `screen -list`'s output.

[image: Putty Settings]

Comment: Awesome thanks :) Feel like a bit of a dumbass for asking now, thought I'd trawled PuTTY options *embarrassed*

Comment: How do I keep the session open (and also see the output of the commands) once they are executed? This seems to close the session as soon as the commands are executed. Not very useful when you just want to run some *client-initiated* commands automatically but continue using the shell.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue server-side when I realized that there was never an instance that I wanted  a terminal that wasn't a screen terminal. I added `screen -aAxRUO` to my `~/.profile` so that any SSH connection to that system (or shell that I open) instantly re-connects to my screen session (without disconnecting the other shells I might have open) or creates a new screen session if it doesn't automatically exist.